# Laravel VuetifySetup

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I followed a tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cXGxO6KCR4g) for Vuetify setup with laravel. I managed to set up the project successfully, i.e. install all dependencies as specified in the tutorial. Although in the final step, NPM watch, I get the following error in the console;

> Uncaught TypeError: _plugins_vuetify__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor

vuetify.js code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Comment: Could you share your code for us?

Comment: try `npm cache clean` then `npm install` then `npm run watch`

Comment: @SMAKSS its quite alot but lol. Basically everything as is in the tutorial.Maybe a particular file you may suspect ?

Comment: I just saw the tutorial you provided but didn't see any particular issue with it, so if you can provide your `main.js` file or the file you tried to import and use the `vuetify` it could be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly lies where you exporting default Vuetify.

The best practice to this is to import Vuetify in the separate file in the plugins for example so I will keep this up with this practice.

So after running:

```
$ npm install vuetify --save
// OR
$ yarn add vuetify
```

to install Vuetify on existing applications through the Webpack or creating a new Vue.js project just like this:

```
$ vue add vuetify
```

You should follow the below instruction.

### Vuetify `v1.5.*`

If you are using Vuetify `v1.5.*` follow the below instruction (otherwise, skip this to the next one)

First of all you don't have to export Vuetify in this version and you just have to import Vuetify and tell Vue to use it. So the `plugins/vuetify.js` should be like this (You can also directly do the following in your `main.js` or `app.js`):

```
// /plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

**NOTE:** You can also define some setting in the above file within the Vue.use and pass it as an object just like this:

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {/*Your setting goes here*/})
```

And then import it like below in your `main.js` or `app.js`:

```
// main.js or app.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css' // You also need to import Vuetify CSS file and also ensure you are using css-loader

import './plugins/vuetify' // We have assuemed the above snippet is in the plugins directory and it lies next to main.js or app.js
...
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
})
```

### Vuetify `v2.*.*`

After adding it through your Webpack you need to locate `webpack.config.js` and add the following setting into your Webpack to configure the loader:

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.s(c|a)ss$/,
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          // Requires sass-loader@^7.0.0
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
            fiber: require('fibers'),
            indentedSyntax: true // optional
          },
          // Requires sass-loader@^8.0.0
          options: {
            implementation: require('sass'),
            sassOptions: {
              fiber: require('fibers'),
              indentedSyntax: true // optional
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

After that just create a plugin directory and then `vuetify.js` file like and add the following into it:

```
// /plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Then navigate to your main entry (`main.js` or `app.js`) and import it like below:

```
// main.js or app.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify' // We have assumed the above snippet is in the plugins directory and it lies next to main.js or app.js

new Vue({
  vuetify,
}).$mount('#app')
```

**NOTE:** This much more sound like an instruction but for more information you can visit the documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start/).

Comment: I do not have a main.js file. What i do have though is an app.js file which is like 4MB, not sure if thats normal ? its in js/app.js in public folder. Is this the same file?

Comment: @JoewyLombe Yea those are exactly the same let me update the solution for you when you are using a single file.

Comment: "export 'default' (imported as 'Vuetify') was not found in '../plugins/vuetify' i get the following error when i remove the "export default"

Comment: @JoewyLombe Oh if you are using `v2.*.*` this might be a problem, I will update the solution for your case.

Comment: @JoewyLombe I just update the answer so let me know if you have a problem with it.

Comment: Any idea where this webpack.config.js file can be found in laravel ? because i found one but its in the vendors folder and theres a rule about not editing anything in that folder. the location is "vendor\facade\ignition".

Comment: Contemplating on just restarting the entire installation from scratch, may have missed something, and this error is driving me nuts !!!

Comment: Do i need to create the webpack.config.js file maybe ?

Comment: Do you see `webpack.mix.js` such a file in your project root directory?

Comment: Hi sorry for the very late response, got so caught up, i've decided to use the plain vue setup and just use laravel as my backend. Managed to get it working this afternoon. But yeah i do have this file(webpack.mix.js) in my root.

Comment: @JoewyLombe It's ok, wish you good luck with your new setup. But anyway you could apply Webpack configs directly in `webpack.mix.js` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! managed to get it to work after following all the steps you provided thoroughly.